# Please help. my parameter estimates are different from what is expected.

Tags: estimation, linear-model, binary-data, logit

I'm building a binary logit model to estimate the crossing behaviour of pedestrians on the freeway. The alternatives (Y|0,1) are: 0 = cross directly and 1 = use a facility. Generic attributes include traffic, time taken to arrive at footbridge, presence of barriers, and 5 more attributes. After running a simple binomial model through BIOGEME, the coefficient for traffic gives a positive value instead of negative.two other attributes are also not interpreting correctly. Please what do I do?

Comment: Are your predictors highly correlated? Sometimes this can cause coefficients to not make sense.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at all of the standard diagnostics to make sure that nothing weird is going on. You might find this very helpful: http://kilpatrick.eeb.ucsc.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/GLMs-Chapter_15.pdf. If you're confident that there's nothing weird going on then this might just be a genuine result.